# Bind handler only once for all elements of a class

Tags: jquery

How to bind a click event to a class .myclass, so that the handler is executed only once for all .myclass elements, and not executed again if the user clicks on another .myclass element.

```
$('.myclass').one('click', function() {...});
```

will execute the handler once per .myclass element, but I need the handler to be executed once, for all .myclass elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the event handler on first click

```
$('.myclass').on('click.custom', function () {
    $('.myclass').off('click.custom');

    // do stuff

});
```

using [namespaced events](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) makes sure you remove that handler only, and not other click handlers.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3USRq/)

Comment: `$(this).off('click.custom');` i think OP wants this.

Comment: @Jai, no, the goal is to remove the handlers from *all* `.myclass` elements, not just the current one.

Comment: @fred _but I need the handler to be executed once, for all .myclass elements._....i think this is the updated one form OP.

Comment: @Jai, yes, that's exactly what we're talking about: *once, for all .myclass elements*. If you only remove the `click` handler from the current element, then clicking on another one will run the handler again (but the handler will only run once for each element).

Comment: ^^^  What @FrédéricHamidi said, the event handler has to be removed for the entire collection, not just `this`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the delegated form of one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/#one-events-selector-data-handlereventObject):

```
$(document).one("click", ".myclass", function() {
    // ...
});
```

I modified [adeneo's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3USRq/1/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: using `one` the handler is executed at most once per element per event type. However OP wants handler to be executed once for all `.myclass` elements.

Comment: @Satal, nope. The delegated form of `one()` will execute the handler at most once because it gets applied to `document`, not to individual `.myclass` elements. Try it :)

Comment: Yup, the only issue is that every click on the document will be filtered agains the class until one of the matching elements is clicked, but that would never be noticeable anyway, so not really a problem.

Comment: @adeneo, true, it probably won't scale as well as your solution. On the other hand, it supports dynamically created `.myclass` elements :)